# How can I delete a subset of a constraint set and add new constraints to this set using c++/cplex?

Tags: c++, constraints, cplex

I have a constraint set for each vehicle "p" and each arc (k,m) that belongs to this vehicle route.
At each iteration, I change the route of a vehicle.
Then, at each iteration, I need to change the constraints related to this vehicle. For a specific "p", I need to delete the constraints related to it and add new ones.
How can I do this?

I don't know how to use the remove function in this case. How can I identify the subset constraints related to "p" to be deleted? In the way I'm doing I'm deleting the always the first constraints of the set.

```
typedef struct{
  IloCplex cplex;
  IloEnv env;
  IloModel mod;
  IloNumVarArray f;
  IloNumArray _f;
  IloNumVarArray q;
  IloNumArray _q;
  IloRangeArray constraints_r3;
  IloObjective fo;
  IloNum _fo;
} CPX_RHLPflow;

struct DATA {

  int n;
  vector<vector<vector<int> > > _x;
  int p;
  vector<double> tau;
};

int MAPf (int router, int nodei, int nodej, int nodeu, int nodev, int N) { 
  return router*N*N*N*N+nodei*N*N*N+nodej*N*N+nodeu*N+nodev;
}


void create_model_RHLPflow(CPX_RHLPflow &mono, DATA data){


  IloEnv& env = mono.env;
  mono.mod = IloModel(env);
  mono.cplex = IloCplex(mono.mod);

  int sizef = data.p*data.n*data.n*data.n*data.n;
  mono.f = IloNumVarArray(env, sizef, 0.0, +IloInfinity, ILOFLOAT);
  mono._f = IloNumArray(env,sizef);
  mono.q = IloNumVarArray(env, data.p, 0.0, +IloInfinity, ILOFLOAT);
  mono._q = IloNumArray(env,data.p);


  mono.constraints_r3 = IloRangeArray(env);

  char name[50];
  for (int p = 0; p < data.p; p++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < data.n; k++) {
      for (int m = 0; m < data.n; m++) { 
    if (k != m) { 
      if (data._x[p][k][m] == 1) { 
        IloExpr r_3(env);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < data.n; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
          if (k != j and m != i) { 
            r_3 += mono.f[MAPf(p,i,j,k,m,data.n)] ; 
            sprintf(name, "f(%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)",p,i,j,k,m);
                    mono.f[MAPf(p,i,j,k,m,data.n)].setName(name);
          }
        }
          }
        }
        r_3 -= mono.q[p] * data.tau[p]; 
        sprintf(name, "q(%d)",p);
            mono.q[p].setName(name);
        IloRange ctr;
        ctr = (r_3 <= 0);
        sprintf(name, "r3_%d_%d_%d",p,k,m);
        ctr.setName(name);
        mono.constraints_r3.add(ctr);
        r_3.end();
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }

  mono.mod.add(mono.constraints_r3);

}

void DeleteConstraints (CPX_RHLPflow &mono, DATA data, int vehicle) {

  char name[50];

  int cont = 0;

  for (int p = 0; p < data.p; p++) {
    if (vehicle == p) {
      for (int k = 0; k < data.n; k++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < data.n; m++) { 
      if (k != m) { 
        if (data._x[p][k][m] == 1) { 
          mono.mod.remove(mono.constraints_r3[cont]);
          cont += 1;
        }
      }
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }



  sprintf(name, "ModelAfterModification.lp");
  mono.cplex.exportModel(name);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  CPX_RHLPflow mono;

  DATA data;
  data.n = 5;
  data.p = 3;

  data._x = vector<vector<vector<int> > > (data.p, vector<vector<int> > (data.n, vector<int> (data.n,0)));
  data.tau = vector<double> (data.p, 1.00);

  data._x[0][0][1] = 1;
  data._x[0][1][3] = 1;
  data._x[0][3][4] = 1;
  data._x[0][4][0] = 1;

  data._x[1][2][4] = 1;
  data._x[1][4][3] = 1;
  data._x[1][3][2] = 1;


  data._x[2][1][2] = 1;
  data._x[2][2][3] = 1;
  data._x[2][3][4] = 1;
  data._x[2][4][1] = 1;

  cout << "oi" << endl;

  create_model_RHLPflow (mono, data);

  char name[50];
  sprintf(name, "ModelBeforeModification.lp");
  mono.cplex.exportModel(name);

  int vehicle = 1;

  DeleteConstraints(mono,data,vehicle);

  data._x[1][2][4] = 0;
  data._x[1][4][3] = 0;
  data._x[1][3][2] = 0;

  data._x[1][2][3] = 1;
  data._x[1][3][1] = 1;
  data._x[1][1][4] = 1;
  data._x[1][4][2] = 1;





  return 0;

}
```

Comment: This isn't really a CPLEX question, its a C++ question. You need to arrange your data structures so that you can find the objects that you need. For example, if you want to be able to delete all the constraints related to 'p', then start by keeping e.g. a list of the constraints for each 'p' when you construct the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If I right understood your question, you can use the solution below.

```
// Insert the constraint
// bc <- my branch-and-cut class
// bc.env_ <- IloEnv
// expr    <- IloExpr
// x       <- integer  
IloRange neigboor(bc.env_, -IloInfinity, expr, x, "constraintName");

// model_ <- IloModel
bc.model_->add(neigboor);

bc.solve();

bc.model_->remove(neigboor);
neigboor.end();
```

You can repeat it indefinitely, adding or removing as many constraints as you want.

I used the above code to perform local searches using CPLEX as neighborhood solver.